# how to release a CF object object correctly?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, core-foundation

I have this method (someone else wrote it!)

```
- (CGPDFDocumentRef)getPdf {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myLocalFileName.pdf"];

    NSURL *pdfURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];

    CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);

    return pdf;
}
```

Now, I've ran Analyze and get three memory leak warnings:

```
Call to function 'CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL' returns a Core Foundation object with a +1 retain count
Object returned to caller as an owning reference (single retain count transferred to caller)
Object leaked: object allocated and stored into 'pdf' is returned from a method whose name ('getPdf') does not start with 'copy', 'mutableCopy', 'alloc' or 'new'.  This violates the naming convention rules given in the Memory Management Guide for Cocoa
```

Could someone please educate me what needs/should be done here ? I understand that I should CFRelease everything with create or copy in the CF function name. What I don't understand is how I can release pdf and still be able to return it at the end of the function. 
What am I missing ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the responsibility of the code receiving the pdf to CFRelease it after they are done with it. Unlike Cocoa, CF does not support autoreleasing, so any object that is returned from a CF function is an object that the caller owns and must deal with.

It is also naming convention that those functions that return a CF object should be named accordingly with `create` or `copy`

Comment: thanks. so when the CGPDFDocumentRef object is returned at the end, its retain count does not change, right ? it's still one and it's the caller's responsibility to make it a 0 (after it's done using it)

Answer (score 6):

You need clang source annotations like as shown here http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2012/01/clang-source-annotations.html

```
    #import <AppKit/AppKit.h>
@interface NSColor (CWNSColorAdditions)
-(CGColorRef)cw_cgColor CF_RETURNS_RETAINED;
@end
```

Comment: I like your answer, it helped me.

Comment: very nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to return an object that you create in your function, the function itself should be named properly to indicate that the object it's returning should be released.

Instead of `getPdf`, you could call your function `createPdf` or `copyPdf`. This will tell the caller that it should call `CFRelease` when it's done, and also satisfy Analyze's request.

Comment: interesting, thank you. so I just by naming the function createPdf or copyPdf "fixes" the memory leak warnings ?

Comment: `copyPDF` and `createPDF` both imply that the function does something other than what it does. Merely adding the word "copy" to a function that has nothing to do with copying is not in line with the spirit of the memory management rules.

Comment: yeah, I've renamed the function to createPdf but still get the same three memory leak warnings.

Comment: @Chuck, that's possibly true, it depends on what this function really means. It looks like `copyPdf` is pretty close to what it does.

Comment: @radvan72, are you sure you're getting the *same* warnings? The last warning explicitly named your function `getPdf`, so if it's no longer named that, it wouldn't say that.

Comment: it turns out this function might be a dud. no1 complained about the function change after I've rebuilt my project. I've searched for calls and I couldn't find one anywhere. I think I'll just comment it out. Still I've learned something. Your help is much appreciated, but I'll mark the other answer as correct since the other needs to level up a bit more. I hope you're cool with it.

Comment: Even if you change the function's name, you still have to release the object at the caller's side (as soon as you are done with the pdf)

Answer (score -1):

```
- (CGPDFDocumentRef)getPdf {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myLocalFileName.pdf"];

    NSURL *pdfURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfPath];

    CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfURL);

    return [pdf autorelease];
}
```

I think this can solve your problem.